# are there similar sites/services like ninite.com

Tags: windows, installation

I'm a programmer but keep the pc's of my relatives healthy, so i often have to install utilities on pc's. I'm looking for a free service/utility which let me bundle these install's in one download and action.

Are there such services and what are is your experience with them ?

I'm on windows, but perhaps there are mixed sites and sites geared to other OS are also welcome.

Comment: This question has a [problem](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: what problem precise ? read the faq but can't see any, i'm wiling to adjust my question

Comment: "what is your experience" is open-ended and invites discussion.

Comment: "are there other sites" ditto

Comment: It matches the pattern “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” which the FAQ asks us to avoid.

Comment: ok i wont mension ninite, just ask for the kind of service, good so ? about the opinion, i need that part, can google it otherwise

Comment: FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Remember this is a Q&A site not suited to discussions (use the "chat" link instead).

Comment: Peter now you are going angry on me......But @RedGrittyBrick is right you can use chat for this kind of questions.

Comment: not angry, i'm no chatter so these long discussions do annoy me, i'm sure the question in its current form won't be a problem

Comment: [Allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/) seems like a solution for this.

Comment: @avirk, didn't know that one, seems very interesting batch installing too and more apps than ninite, why don't you make an answer of it ?

Comment: @peter other user has add this in his answer you can mark it as solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to extend your search scope a bit you might want to look at

https://www.soluto.com/
or 
http://allmyapps.com/

While I do not think if allows you to bundle installs together it is a very good way of managing software remotely on multiple computers (Soluto is particularly good at managing relatives computers).

Comment: thanks justin, allmyapps seems interesting, only when i download a package nothing happens when i execute the file, since they closed the question i give the answer to you, you were the only one who was constructive

Comment: @peter I downloaded the exe and running it on my PC and its working like a charm. Personally I liked it over ninite.com. :)

Comment: found ou what was wrong, you first had to start the manager that is installed, which means jou have some soft permanently installed on your system just to do the installing/updating which isn't the case with ninite which works cleaner. Also you have to do much of the configuring yourself when the packages install, which again ninite does way better, for the rest it's bigger and has more options..